# Proper way to discretize a parametric spline surface

Tags: mesh, splines, discretization

Given that I have a triangular mesh model defined in obj format (`1590 vertices and 300 faces`), I reconstruct it to a single B-spline surface.

[image]

Now I want to export the generated B-spline surface to a triangular mesh similar to the *original one*.

#### Surface definition

> Due to the stack website limiting the number of characters, please download it from https://github.com/LavenderNPU/Test/blob/main/control-points-40x40.csv

```
P = Partition[Import["local-file", "CSV"], 40); (* due to stack website limits the number of the characters, please download it from https://github.com/LavenderNPU/Test/blob/main/control-points-40x40.csv *)
U = {0,0,0,0,0.027027,0.0540541,0.0810811,0.108108,0.135135,0.162162,0.189189,0.216216,0.243243,0.27027,0.297297,0.324324,0.351351,0.378378,0.405405,0.432432,0.459459,0.486486,0.513514,0.540541,0.567568,0.594595,0.621622,0.648649,0.675676,0.702703,0.72973,0.756757,0.783784,0.810811,0.837838,0.864865,0.891892,0.918919,0.945946,0.972973,1,1,1,1};
V = {0,0,0,0,0.027027,0.0540541,0.0810811,0.108108,0.135135,0.162162,0.189189,0.216216,0.243243,0.27027,0.297297,0.324324,0.351351,0.378378,0.405405,0.432432,0.459459,0.486486,0.513514,0.540541,0.567568,0.594595,0.621622,0.648649,0.675676,0.702703,0.72973,0.756757,0.783784,0.810811,0.837838,0.864865,0.891892,0.918919,0.945946,0.972973,1,1,1,1};
mask = BSplineFunction[P, SplineDegree -> {3, 3}, SplineKnots -> {U, V}];

ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

#### Trial-1

```
p2 = Graphics3D@First@ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50];
DiscretizeGraphics[Normal[p2 /. (Lighting -> _) :> Lighting -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

Obviously, the quality of `DiscretizeGraphics[]` is lower than the original one.

#### Trial-2

```
 ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 30, Mesh -> All]

 Export["mask-mma.obj", %]
```

[image]

However, `PlotPoints -> 30` and `Mesh -> All` will introduce more vertices (`2859`) than the original obj file (`1590 vertices`).

So I would like to know if there is a proper method to generate a triangular mesh similar to the original one (fewer vertices and good triangle distribution)

Comment: Your `f[u,v]` is undefined. Perhaps you need to edit your question.

Comment: The code doesn't work, Maybe the best way is directly post `U` and `V` or `P`.

Comment: @cvgmt Sorry for the missing data. I have updated the question. The `P` is very large and the stack site limits the number of characters, please download it to PC and then import it.

Comment: Have you tried OpenCascadeLink?

Comment: @user21 No, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

- Not an answer. Since the original code does not run, here we modified some part of the code.
- `ArrayReshape` the data `P` to `40*40*3` since there are `1600` points.
- Replace the download link of the data `P`.

```
Clear[P, U, V, mask];
P = Import[
   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LavenderNPU/Test/main/control-\
points-40x40.csv", "CSV"];
U = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.027027, 0.0540541, 0.0810811, 0.108108, 0.135135, 
   0.162162, 0.189189, 0.216216, 0.243243, 0.27027, 0.297297, 
   0.324324, 0.351351, 0.378378, 0.405405, 0.432432, 0.459459, 
   0.486486, 0.513514, 0.540541, 0.567568, 0.594595, 0.621622, 
   0.648649, 0.675676, 0.702703, 0.72973, 0.756757, 0.783784, 
   0.810811, 0.837838, 0.864865, 0.891892, 0.918919, 0.945946, 
   0.972973, 1, 1, 1, 1};
V = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.027027, 0.0540541, 0.0810811, 0.108108, 0.135135, 
   0.162162, 0.189189, 0.216216, 0.243243, 0.27027, 0.297297, 
   0.324324, 0.351351, 0.378378, 0.405405, 0.432432, 0.459459, 
   0.486486, 0.513514, 0.540541, 0.567568, 0.594595, 0.621622, 
   0.648649, 0.675676, 0.702703, 0.72973, 0.756757, 0.783784, 
   0.810811, 0.837838, 0.864865, 0.891892, 0.918919, 0.945946, 
   0.972973, 1, 1, 1, 1};
mask = BSplineFunction[ArrayReshape[P, {40, 40, 3}], 
   SplineDegree -> {3, 3}, SplineKnots -> {U, V}];
surf = ParametricPlot3D[mask[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50]
```

- `MaxRecursion -> 0` can prevent Mathematica to add extra points.

```
surf1 = ParametricPlot3D[mask[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 30, Mesh -> All, MaxRecursion -> 0]
Export["mask-mma.obj", surf1]
```

- It seems that `DiscretizeGraphics` only support polygon, does not using B-Spline surface as the basic element. According to the `DiscretizeGraphics` document,"Nonlinear Graphics primitives can only be approximately represented"

```
Graphics3D[
 BSplineSurface[Partition[P, 40], SplineDegree -> {3, 3}, 
  SplineKnots -> {U, V}]]
```

Comment: cvgmt, thanks for making it work.